# Testing broadcast API without connecting to page

Tags: chatfuel

i have a bot which is in test mode, so still not connected to a page. is it possible to test the broadcast API?

right now i'm getting "Bad Data: Bot page not found", but i'm hoping that i did something wrong.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to create a page and make it unpublished and you will be able to see the results